# What does "part of a design and manipulated accordingly" mean in a stock photography license?

Tags: stock-photography, licensing

I notice many if not all of the stock photography providers carry something to this effect in the license.
I am using [Photo Dune](http://photodune.net/licenses/photo) as an example

> “Distribution or displaying of any Work in any digital format at a resolution greater than 1000×1000 pixels in on–line or electronic publications, including web pages, unless it is included in your site’s design. If the image is part of a design and manipulated accordingly, the image width can be higher than 1000 pixels.”

Surely all images were “part of a design”

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that an image cannot stand independently if greater than 1000 pixels. This would be using the image itself as the primary design, where if the image is incorporated into a larger design and the image is not the primary object, then you are in the clear. This stipulation is often to prevent the image being sold as artwork by a person other than the photographer or making that quality available online for someone else to do so.

I'd also like to refer this question to the graphic design forum since this is a design question and not a photography question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com